# How can a client-side user get an SSL key?

Tags: ssl, iis-7.5

I have an IIS 7.5 web server with an SSL certificate setup as follows: 
Select "Default Web Site" -> Bindings:
Type: https (all other types removed)
IP address: All Unassigned
Port: 443
SSL certificate: mycert.pfx

I have a C# client application that accesses the URL for the site above. If the user just tries to connect, the connection fails because they do not have the mycert.pfx certificate file installed.

When the clients were on Windows 7, we just told them to open the URL in Internet Explorer. This required them to "Proceed Anyway - Not Recommended". The URL bar would turn red, and the user could follow steps to download/install the certificate with Internet Explorer. After that, the application always worked.

In Windows 10, the default Internet Explorer does not offer a "Proceed Anyway - Not Recommended" link. If I keychain the mycert.pfx file to their machine and install, the client application connects to the server and everything works.

Finally, here's my question: How do people handle certificate file deployments in a large commercial environment? The .pfx certificate has to be renewed every year, so just adding it to the application installer is only a short term fix. Is there a typical way to install/update .pfx files for clients?

Answer (score 0):

Randy

Your pfx files should never be shared with the client. the public key chain is shared with the client. PFX file contains the private key of the certificate which you have procured from a CA which must never be shared.

The client application will verify the certificate chain received from the server with the public root and intermediates which are pre installed in its certificate store.